# Should I use Civi::settings()->get and set or

Tags: settings, coding-standards

In this post on StackExchange [How do I add a new settings page for my extension?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/how-do-i-add-a-new-settings-page-for-my-extension) the way to create settings in CiviCRM is stated as : Create a settings dir in your extension's base directory, and within that create a whateveryouwant.setting.php.

I always use Civi::settings()->set and Civi::settings()->get. What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create settings using [Setting Reference](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/setting/)

How I would do through extension is

- Register metadata for setting using [hook_civicrm_alterSettingsMetaData](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterSettingsMetaData/)
- To set the setting using civicrm api 
  code:

  civicrm_api3('Setting', 'create', [
    'setting_name_goes_here' => 123,
  ]);
- To get the setting using civicrm api

  civicrm_api3('Setting', 'getvalue', [
        'name' =>'setting_name_goes_here',
      ]);
- If you want to add this setting on one of the Admin config form then below is a good example on how you can do it.(New version of CiviCRM provides more flexibility to add settings to UI by appending settings in $form->_settings in preprocess hook)

  - https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.easybatch/blob/master/easybatch.php#L140
  - https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.easybatch/blob/master/easybatch.php#L116
  - https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.easybatch/blob/master/easybatch.php#L304
  - https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.easybatch/blob/master/templates/CRM/EasyBatch/Form/Admin.tpl

Comment: I know this is an alternative, but why would I go through all that trouble if Civi::settings->set suffices to create my setting?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Jon G, that makes sense :-) So summarizing the recommended way is:

- Register metadata for setting using `hook_civicrm_alterSettingsMetaData` or create `myfile.setting.php` in my extension
- Use either Civi::settings()->set to set the value of the setting and Civi::settings()->get to retrieve the value OR the Setting API.

Comment: I'd +1 for using `Civi::settings()` methods. The API is a terrible pattern (security risk, unless you know about it and mitigate this - [example](https://github.com/artfulrobot/chasse/blob/master/chasse.php#L216)) and if we can all stop using it then we might be able to improve it without breaking stuff. Also, the API includes lots of params that aren't(/don't seem to be) needed any more, like settings group. This too can lead you to mistakes like naming a setting "api_key" because you thought your settings group was a namespace; it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `hook_civicrm_alterSettingsMetaData` you can also create a `myfile.setting.php` file in your extension.

See also issue [core#495](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/495) for recent work that allows you to add settings to the UI based SOLELY on metadata - very exciting!

Comment: I know I can do this @JonG, can you tell me why I would need to create such a file and metadata? If I just include Civi::settings->set my setting is created?

Comment: If you have the metadata (either via the hook or settings.php) then a) it will appear in the API Explorer, b) you can put it on a settings page with no code.